# Text embed not working in CSS

Tags: css, text, embed

I've tried to embed a font and nothing is showing up. I just get a random serif font on every page. Code I'm using...

```
/*fonts*/
@font-face {
font-family: 'toltbold';
src: url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l001-webfont-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l001-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l001-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l001-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l001-webfont-webfont.svg#titilliumtext25l800_wt')    format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'tiltbody';
src: url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l003-webfont-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l003-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded -opentype'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l003-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l003-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/titilliumtext25l003-webfont-webfont.svg#titilliumtext25l400_wt')  format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

And the text formatting part is...

```
/*Text formatting*/
.heading {color: #000; font-size: 28px; font-family: tiltbold; line-height: 14px;}
.bodybold {color: #000; font-size: 18px; font-family: tiltbold; line-height: 14px;}
.body {color: #000; font-size: 18px; font-family: tiltbody; line-height: 20px;}
.bodyred {color: #000; font-size: 18px; font-family: tiltbody; line-height: 14px;}
.warning {color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; font-family: tiltbody; line-height: 14px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute link in your src:url(''); area. If this fixes the issue it means the font files are in the wrong directory or there could be an issue with .htaccess rewriting.